Using member functions inside windows procedures (using c++)
I am creating a windows application. I am trying to set up an Application class and handle events in a member function inside it, and have an instance of the class declared beforehand to be called inside the windows procedure.
I expect seeing a white unresponsive window but the window creation returns nullptr. This is the main.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include "WinApplication.h"

WinApplication* app;

LRESULT CALLBACK windowCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    return app->appCallback(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    app = new WinApplication();
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = TEXT("Window Class");
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = windowCallback;
    
    // Register Class
    if (!RegisterClass(&window_class))
        return 1;
    
    // Create Window
    HWND window = CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, TEXT("MyApp"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, DEF_WIDTH, DEF_HEIGHT, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    
    app->init(window);
    while (true) {  }

    return 0;
}

and this is the member callback:
LRESULT WinApplication::appCallback(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return 0;
}

Any help would be appreciated

If you don't handle a message use return DefWindowProc(...). The endless loop without a message pump will also be a problem.

You're focused on the member function. What happens if you eliminate it? (Have windowCallback return 0 directly instead of going through app->appCallback.) If this does not change your symptom, you have established that the member function has nothing to do with your current issue.

uncommenting the first line in windowCallback fixes the problem, but I don't have a way to access the data inside the WinApplication object this way

You can call DefWindowProc inside your class method and return the value it returns. You could also use SetWindowLongPtr and GetWindowLongPtr with GWLP_USERDATA to store and retrieve the this pointer you need to call the member function and eliminate the need for a global.

Since the WinApplication object is global, there is no need to store it in the HWND.  But, if you needed to create multiple windows, each one with its own class object, then yes GWLP_USERDATA would make sense to use.

@DanielHamzany "uncommenting the first line in windowCallback fixes the problem" -- That first line does not uniformly return 0, so it is not an apples-to-apples comparison to your member function. To get a good comparison, you should either have windowCallback always return 0; or have appCallback accept another parameter so that it can return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); (the commented-out line). You can remove the extra parameter later, once you've figured out the problem.

Why naked new? Prefer using smart pointers that will keep track of ownership and release resources automaticaly. :)

So you create your app instance but what happens if RegisterClass() returns false? What happens if CreateWindow() fails? From the looks of the code, you assume it will always work.

Does this answer your question? CreateWindowEx returns NULL

The problem is that your windowCallback() is not calling DefWindowProc() and returning its return value.  When you receive WM_NCCREATE and return 0 (FALSE) for it, CreateWindow() aborts the window creation:

If an application processes this message, it should return TRUE to continue creation of the window. If the application returns FALSE, the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function will return a NULL handle.

Also, you need a message loop for your windowCallback() to continue receiving messages for the window after CreateWindow() is finished creating it.
Try this instead:
#include <windows.h>
#include "WinApplication.h"

WinApplication *app;

LRESULT CALLBACK windowCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return app->appCallback(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WinApplication appInst;
    app = &appInst;

    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.hInstance = hInstance;
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = TEXT("Window Class");
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = windowCallback;
    
    // Register Class
    if (!RegisterClass(&window_class))
        return 1;
    
    // Create Window
    HWND window = CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, TEXT("MyApp"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, DEF_WIDTH, DEF_HEIGHT, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    if (!window)
        return 1;

    appInst.init(window);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT WinApplication::appCallback(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // handle messages as needed...
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


Then, consider taking it a step further my moving all of the logic inside of the WinApplication class itself.  You can pass the class' this pointer to the lpParam parameter of CreateWindow() and receive it in your windowCallback() via WM_NCCREATE, and then save it inside the HWND for use in later messages, eg:
class WinApplication
{
    HWND hwnd;

    static LRESULT CALLBACK windowCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    LRESULT appCallback(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

public:
    WinApplication(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    ~WinApplication();

    void run();
};

WinApplication::WinApplication(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.hInstance = hInstance;
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = TEXT("Window Class");
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = &WinApplication::windowCallback;
    
    // Register Class
    if (!RegisterClass(&window_class))
        throw 1;
    
    // Create Window
    hwnd = CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, TEXT("MyApp"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, DEF_WIDTH, DEF_HEIGHT, 0, 0, hInstance, this);
    if (!hwnd)
        throw 1;
}

WinApplication::~WinApplication() {
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinApplication::windowCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    WinApplication *app;
    if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
        app = static_cast<WinApplication*>(
            reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams
        );
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(app));
        app->hwnd = hwnd;
    }
    else {
        app = reinterpret_cast<WinApplication*>(
            GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)
        );
        if (!app)
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return app->appCallback(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT WinApplication::appCallback(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    // handle messages as needed...
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void WinApplication::run() {
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { 
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

#include <windows.h>
#include "WinApplication.h"

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    WinApplication appInst(hInstance);
    appInst.run();
    return 0;
}

